# Is this the right way to use Asymptote in LaTeX?

Tags: asymptote

[image]

This is the code i have written:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany]{book}

\usepackage{asymptote} 

\begin{document} 

\begin{asydef} 
import three; 
import solids; 
\end{asydef}

\begin{asy} 
draw((0,0)--(100,100))

\end{asy}

\end{document}
```

This is whats written down there:

```
Package asymptote Warning: file `asymptote-1.pdf' not found on input line 15.

(asymptote.aux) )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on asymptote.log.

Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:/Users/OEM/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/texify.log

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
```

I have already downloaded the asymptote package... what have I done wrong?
I am merely following the instructions here:

[image]

To be honest, I have been using LaTeX for a while now but im still new to Asymptote.......Im desperately trying to draw my first Asymptote graphic ---even a straight line would be good.....but i havent had any progress 
am i doing everything right? Or have I done everything wrong? Do i draw an Asymptote graphic in LaTeX this way? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this way works *if* you add the missing semicolon at the end of the `draw` command: `draw((0,0)--(100,100));` and if you run `asy`. Assuming that your file name is `main.tex`, you need to run `asy main-1.asy`. Could be that your compiler automatically invokes `asy`, in which case you only need to add the `;`.

Comment: what does it mean to "run asy"? Sorry if it sounds like a stupid question haha

Comment: Look in `asymptote.log` to find the errors from running asymptote. The only thing TeX  "knows" is that asymptote didn't produce anything it could include in your document - it doesn't know *why* asymptote didn't run successfully.

Comment: `asy` is a compiler that converts your `asymptote` code to a graphics that can be included by the TeX file.

Comment: so，um, how do I “run“ this asy thing? Sorry XP

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 (the first latex step):

```
latex main.tex
```

Step 2 (the asy step):

```
asy main-1.asy
```

Step 3 (the second/final latex step):

```
latex main.tex
```